# Continuity of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

$ x^2\sin{1/y} \hspace{0.5cm} \text{if } y\neq0 $

$ 0 \hspace{1.9cm} \text{if } y=0 $

The question is to analyse the continuity of the function at (0,0).

ps: I've used the consecutive limits method and found the function discontinuous at the given point. I wonder whether I should have solved by $ y = mx $ or not.

Comment: Hint:Let $f$ your function.  You have for all $(x,y)$ $$|f(x,y)|\leq x^2\leq x^2+y^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to see this is continuous is to notice that you have something bounded $\sin(1/y)$ times something that tends to $0$, $x^2$ and the function is defined as $0$ at the origin.

More rigorously, 
$$
|x^2\sin(1/y)|\leq x^2\rightarrow 0,x\rightarrow0
$$

Comment: It made sense with the inequality, thanks.

Comment: no problem. Remember you can usually switch limits to zero to limits to infinity, if you are more comfortable with these, by taking the reciprocal of things.